# problem trying release upgrade Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

When I was updating to have the new version I had many problems, I did the update but in the process the computer turn off and reboot and gave me problems like:

> stopped getty on tty1

or

> a start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up(6 min 3s/no limit)

After that I did something like a quick solution but the system still have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all look for files at /var/crash. Sometimes you get a message at startup just because some crash files are there without deleting. If that is the case, just run:

sudo rm /var/crash/*

If the problem persists perhaps you need to reinstall ubuntu. I had some problems upgrading to 16.04 and had to reinstall preserving partitions using manual configuration, and selecting no format option. Previously I did a backup of /home directory but I did needed.

Comment: +jose miguel do you  speak spanish i can understand you beter

Comment: Yo tuve problemas también al actualizar a la 16.04 en uno de mis ordenadores. Quedó inservible, pero es factible arrancar desde el pendrive de instalación y, cuando pida elegir las particiones, seleccionar particiones manuales y asignar el root a donde lo tuvieras previamente. Yo seguí la segunda opción de esta explicación: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: Lo otro que te decía es que mirases en no haya nada en la carpeta /var/crash ya que siempre que ahí hay ficheros de aplicaciones que han fallado, sale un mensaje diciendo que ha habido un problema. Lo que yo hago cuando pasa eso es borrar el contenido manualmente con un "sudo rm /var/crash/*". Así, hasta que vuelve a fallar otro programa, no vuelves a ver el mensaje de que Ubuntu ha tenido un problema.

Comment: gracias miguel por tus explicaciones ,me sirvio

Comment: fue la segunda opcion la que tome sudo rm /var/crash/*

Comment: De vez en cuando te pasará que tendrás que borrarlo. A mi me pasaba bastante con el 15.10 con un poste de aplicaciones.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿podrías aceptar la repuesta como correcta? Gracias

Comment: como se añade como correcta?

Comment: A la persona que pregunta le debe aparecer una opción para marcar la respuesta como "accepted"

Comment: ya esta y gracias !!   ; )

Comment: oye una pregunta?

Comment: si tengo algunos problemas , o simplemente cuestiones  sobre ubuntu ¿puedo preguntarte? ¿no? si me responderias siempre wue tengas tiempo claro

Comment: y ademas es que no se mucho de ubuntu aunque lleve ya casi un año ;  )

Comment: gracias de todos modos ;   )

Comment: Si me sé la respuesta... :) saludos